# How to install cvat on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, service, manifest, podspec, cvat

I have tried to develop kubernetes manifest files but it seems to be a tough task so i am searching for other approach. please share links to instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to following links to get some help:

1. https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/cvat/tree/develop/helm-chart
2. https://github.com/Kapernikov/cvat-helm
3. Detailed discussion at https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/cvat/issues/1087